# KeyTime property on KeyFrame object must be set to a non-negative TimeSpan value

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to write an ad-control to implement to all my pages of app. 
this usercontrol only contain a "layoutRoot" grid, and an "AdMob" grid, which at first I want to hide and only show after the "time_show_banner" time. I try to binding this variable but it only return the error at the title.

in c# code:

```
public string time_show_banner { get; set; }
```

my user-control:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Black" Height="60">   
    <Grid x:Name="AdMob" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">            
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform TranslateY="70"/>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
    </Grid>
    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="AdMob">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="0"
            KeyTime="{Binding time_show_banner ,Converter={StaticResource ConvertKeyTime}}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>
</Grid>
```

the convert:

```
public class ConvertKeyTime : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string d = value.ToString();
        string a = "0:0:" + d;
        return a;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: please add the value you are returning from the converter

Answer (score 2):

Your converter should return a `TimeSpan`, not a string:

```
public object Convert(
    object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var seconds = (double)value;
    return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);
}
```

The `Convert` method assumes that the property is of type `double` and returns the time in seconds:

```
public double time_show_banner { get; set; } // seconds
```

---

That said, a better solution might be to directly declare the property as `TimeSpan`. You won't need a converter at all:

```
public TimeSpan time_show_banner { get; set; }
```